# Failed to install github-pages on windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby, github-pages, rdiscount

I am trying to build website using Jekyll in Github Pages, I have issues installing github-pages gem in my local machine Windows 7 x64 Enterprise version.

Here is the steps I took:
* installed ruby 2.1.7 32bit at c:\Ruby21\ (file rubyinstaller-2.1.7.exe)
* installed corresponding devkit at c:\Devkit\ (file DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe)
* run “gem install json --platform=ruby” to install RubyGems library JSON
* confirm JSON gem ok: ruby -rubygems -e "require 'json'; puts JSON.load('[42]').inspect, I got response 42.

- run “gem install bundler”, installed ok.
- I went to local repo, created a Gemfile with content:

  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'github-pages'
- run "bundle install"

The last run was failed with following message:

```
Installing rdiscount 2.1.7 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for random()... no
checking for srandom()... no
checking for rand()... yes
checking for srand()... yes
checking size of unsigned long... 4
checking size of unsigned int... failed
checking size of unsigned short... failed
no int with size 2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby
        --with-rdiscount-dir
        --without-rdiscount-dir
        --with-rdiscount-include
        --without-rdiscount-include=${rdiscount-dir}/include
        --with-rdiscount-lib
        --without-rdiscount-lib=${rdiscount-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rdiscount-2.1.7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/rdiscount-2.1.7/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rdiscount (2.1.7), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rdiscount -v '2.1.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Below is the content of the file gem_make.out:

```
have_func: checking for random()... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'random' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))random; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'random' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvoe3lp.o: In function `t':
C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems\rdiscount-2.1.7\ext/conftest.c:16: undefined reference to `random'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { random(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for srandom()... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'srandom' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))srandom; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'srandom' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPnlJQk.o: In function `t':
C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems\rdiscount-2.1.7\ext/conftest.c:16: undefined reference to `srandom'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { srandom(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rand()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rand; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for srand()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))srand; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

check_sizeof: checking size of unsigned long... -------------------- 4

"gcc -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration   -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:9:5: error: size of array 'conftest_const' is negative
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: typedef unsigned long rbcv_typedef_;
6: static rbcv_typedef_ *rbcv_ptr_;
7: 
8: /*top*/
9: int conftest_const[(sizeof((*rbcv_ptr_)) < 0) ? 1 : -1];
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: typedef unsigned long rbcv_typedef_;
 6: static rbcv_typedef_ *rbcv_ptr_;
 7: 
 8: #include <stdio.h>
 9: /*top*/
10: typedef unsigned
11: #ifdef PRI_LL_PREFIX
12: #define PRI_CONFTEST_PREFIX PRI_LL_PREFIX
13: LONG_LONG
14: #else
15: #define PRI_CONFTEST_PREFIX "l"
16: long
17: #endif
18: conftest_type;
19: conftest_type conftest_const = (conftest_type)(sizeof((*rbcv_ptr_)));
20: int main() {printf("%"PRI_CONFTEST_PREFIX"u\n", conftest_const); return 0;}
/* end */

./conftest |
--------------------

check_sizeof: checking size of unsigned int... -------------------- failed

"gcc -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration   -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:9:5: error: size of array 'conftest_const' is negative
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: typedef unsigned int rbcv_typedef_;
6: static rbcv_typedef_ *rbcv_ptr_;
7: 
8: /*top*/
9: int conftest_const[(sizeof((*rbcv_ptr_)) < 0) ? 1 : -1];
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
c:/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file conftest.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: typedef unsigned int rbcv_typedef_;
 6: static rbcv_typedef_ *rbcv_ptr_;
 7: 
 8: #include <stdio.h>
 9: /*top*/
10: typedef unsigned
11: #ifdef PRI_LL_PREFIX
12: #define PRI_CONFTEST_PREFIX PRI_LL_PREFIX
13: LONG_LONG
14: #else
15: #define PRI_CONFTEST_PREFIX "l"
16: long
17: #endif
18: conftest_type;
19: conftest_type conftest_const = (conftest_type)(sizeof((*rbcv_ptr_)));
20: int main() {printf("%"PRI_CONFTEST_PREFIX"u\n", conftest_const); return 0;}
/* end */

--------------------

check_sizeof: checking size of unsigned short... -------------------- failed

"gcc -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration   -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:9:5: error: size of array 'conftest_const' is negative
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: typedef unsigned short rbcv_typedef_;
6: static rbcv_typedef_ *rbcv_ptr_;
7: 
8: /*top*/
9: int conftest_const[(sizeof((*rbcv_ptr_)) < 0) ? 1 : -1];
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby21/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
c:/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file conftest.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: typedef unsigned short rbcv_typedef_;
 6: static rbcv_typedef_ *rbcv_ptr_;
 7: 
 8: #include <stdio.h>
 9: /*top*/
10: typedef unsigned
11: #ifdef PRI_LL_PREFIX
12: #define PRI_CONFTEST_PREFIX PRI_LL_PREFIX
13: LONG_LONG
14: #else
15: #define PRI_CONFTEST_PREFIX "l"
16: long
17: #endif
18: conftest_type;
19: conftest_type conftest_const = (conftest_type)(sizeof((*rbcv_ptr_)));
20: int main() {printf("%"PRI_CONFTEST_PREFIX"u\n", conftest_const); return 0;}
/* end */

--------------------
```

I don't have background on c. I am not sure what the issue is and how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated!

PS:

I've tried different Ruby versions(2.1.7/2.2.3) and x86/x64, all resulted the same error. I also tried in another machine with win7 ultimate and installation without any error. I am suspecting there is some error specific to this particular win7 ent machine.

The cmd I ran is with admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly related: You have a 64-bit OS but are using a 32-bit Ruby. Try a 64-bit Ruby (and DevKit).

You might also try Ruby 2.2.2, which is explicitly tested on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've tried different Ruby versions and x86/x64, all resulted the same error. I also tried in another machine with win7 ultimate and installation without any error. I am suspecting there is some error specific to this particular win7 ent machine.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Windows 7 x64, ruby 2.0.0p647 (2015-08-18) [x64-mingw32], x64 DevKit.

Comment: Same error with ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: @gazareth: As mentioned above. If you are running a 64-bit OS, try a 64-bit Ruby (i.e. mingw64). Doesn't work? Try it on a fresh VM. Still doesn't work? Poke me.

Comment: @DavidFoster I installed Ruby from the installer "rubyinstaller-2.2.3-x64" from rubyinstallers.org which should be x64, though I do note that 'ruby -v' does return the line above with "mingw32" in. DevKit is from installer "DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx". I don't have the option of installing on a VM as I'm using my work machine.

Comment: Okay. RDiscount is tested on 64-bit Windows in the continuous integration system, so the most likely issue is some environmental issue on your machine or Ruby 2.2.3 broke something compared to Ruby 2.2.2.